# Can I get zsh to include the directory stack in tab completion for tilde (~)?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have `autocd`, `autopushd` and `pushdminus` enabled. When I try tab completion with `~`:

```
$ ~<Tab>
avahi  ftp  mail        redsocks  systemd-coredump         systemd-timesync
bin    gdm  nm-openvpn  root      systemd-journal-gateway  tor
#… other users
```

And if I try with `~1`, `~2`, etc:

```
$ ~2<Tab>
~2    /tmp
```

Can I get zsh to include the expansions of directory stack shortcuts when completing just `~`?

Something like:

```
$ ~<Tab>
~1    /etc
~2    /tmp
…
avahi  ftp  mail        redsocks  systemd-coredump         systemd-timesync
bin    gdm  nm-openvpn  root      systemd-journal-gateway  tor
```